# SQL Query to keep a running lowest value

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 fields:

```
Period  Time
1   4562
2   4555
3   4570
4   4558
5   4550
6   4570
7   4565
8   4545
9   4550
10  4560
```

For each period I would like to keep the lowest time in another field so the table would look like this:

```
Period  Time    Lowest
1   4562    4562
2   4555    4555
3   4570    4555
4   4558    4555
5   4550    4550
6   4570    4550
7   4565    4550
8   4545    4545
9   4550    4545
10  4560    4545
```

Thanks

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: How do you determine "lowest" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a cumulative minimum.  You can use ISO/ANSI standard window functions:

```
select t.*,
       min(time) over (order by id) as lowest
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select *,min(time) over (order by period) from YOURTABLENAME
```

SQL Server 2014